# Podcast App Double Speed Missing?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts

Apple, in their infinite wisdom, has changed the Podcast app (again).  Am I going crazy, or has double speed been removed?

Comment: Found it!  I quick tap of the album art reveals the scrub bar and the double speed.   Grrr, Apple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's still there!

Between the podcast artwork and the progress bar, tap the 1x icon to change the speed. On iPhone 4S and below, tap on the artwork to bring it up.

[image: podcasts screenshot]